# What is the essence of stoicism?

Tags: ethics, practical-ethics, stoicism

I am a materialist, and I heard that stoic philosophers can be described (to some extent) as materialists. I am a big fan of stoic logic and ethical philosophy (and attitude towards death, emotions, virtue...etc) and I can relate to this philosophy and tradition.

Thing is, I am hesitant as to whether I can call myself **a stoic** or not. So, what I am asking is what is the essence of stoicism and what are its additional attributes?

That is, what makes you a stoic (the pillars of stoicism if you will), and what is an attribute (a mere happy coincidence for some stoic philosophers to share).

The most I am interested in here is physics, metaphysics and epistemology : I have read about some stoic philosphers who say that there is a soul (pneuma), and I personally do not believe that a soul exists as a separate entity that can live on after death. Of course, some stoics (if not all) believed that this pneuma is itself *only finely* material (very fine matter), which *saves* some degree of materialism.

But I do not know whether these mind, epistemological and metaphysical theories are essential to be a stoic, or whether I should concern myself with them at all?

And I like the word *stoicism*, which makes me more careful to not use a beautiful word and sound ignorant.

Comment: The core of Stoicism has been ethics, at least since the Roman times. Their epistemology is broadly naturalist/empiricist, so you are already a Stoic. As for metaphysics, ancient Stoics had a peculiar mix of God with materialism (World Soul made of material pneuma), but it plays very little role in [modern Stoicism](https://www.iep.utm.edu/stoicism/#H6), if any. I suppose some sort of pantheism or panpsychism would be modern descendants of it.

Comment: @Conifold Thank you so much for your reply, so : one can say that it is more likely  that a philosophical tradition (unlike a specific philosophy that studies a very narrow subject) is able to tolerate some level of diversity that does not challenge its core ideas and concepts. Thanks for the link.

Comment: As Conifold notes Stoicism has no systematic metaphysical theory, so you can be Stoic and a Materialist. This is its appeal to many people. It claims the Unity of All but rejects the philosophy that accompanies this claim so is fundamentally philosophically flawed, leaving its teachings metaphysically ungrounded, but its ethics are appealing to many people and roughly follow along the lines of the Perennial tradition. It's as close as a Materialist can get to the Perennial view without having to change their core belief.

Comment: I think it is true of any philosophical school of thought that lasts and attracts multiple prominent thinkers. For example, two founders of pragmatism, Peirce and James, disagreed on a cardinal metaphysical question: the former was a realist, the latter not. Two major phenomenologists, Heidegger and Husserl, disagreed over objectivity of ideas, etc.

Comment: @PeterJ, I agree ... I see similarities between stoicism and buddhism in particular, and I am myself a big fan of buddhism to some extent, you can say that I am like 60 to 80 percent okay with taoism, buddhism, the hindu advaita vedanta and the ideas in the upanishads...etc . For instance, although I do not believe in an immaterial soul, I believe that more likely, my consciousness will be generated again in another brain on another planet if existence is infinite i.e : since I am then I am possible, which implies tha if there's infinity the the possible will repeat for infinity.

Comment: Not exactly in the same life, maybe my 'I', this consciousness if it can be repeated , the it lived an infinite amount of lives that are not alike ... maybe I was born before as an alien .. who knows? I am just saying that it's more likely. And it is not like there is a soul that survives death .. i don't believe in souls. This is just an example ...Thanks

Comment: Yes Conifold, it is because these philosophies are not the essence of pragmatism, there are even idealist people who are realists , plato is an 'idealist'in the sense of holding the view that the real world is just a shadow of an immaterial universal reality of ideas or forms, that our world is an illusion. At the same time he is a realist with regards to the view that those ideas are not mere conceptions of mind but also that they exist as a separate objective reality ... I mean, these names are very tricky. Even one person can identify with two opposite names in different contexts.

Comment: @Conifold - I personally doubt that James and Peirce disagreed much, under the superficial stuff, although feel Peirce had a much better grasp of intricacies of the philosophical issues. It is simply not true that all prominent schools of thought have no metaphysical ground. Stoicism is not part of the perennial tradition.precisely because it is without one. .   ;

Comment: @PeterJ  Depends on what is considered superficial, aside from realism Peirce called James's theory of truth "disastrous". But the point was not that schools have no metaphysical ground but rather that they tolerate major disagreements on non-core issues (which metaphysics is in Stoicism or pragmatism).

Comment: @Conifold - Okay. I'd agree that for Stoicism metaphyscis is not a core issue and this would be my complaint. But some schools tolerate disagreement on metahysical issues, some don't, so I find your claim too sweeping. Some schools are schools precisely because they share a metaphysic. I'm a big fan of Peirce but not so much James, so can't go too deep into their disagreements.      .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stoicism is primarily a virtue ethics grounded on logic and physics. As [Massimo Pigliucci describes](https://www.iep.utm.edu/stoicism/#H2) this:

> A fundamental aspect of Stoic philosophy is the twofold idea that ethics is central to the effort, and that the study of ethics is to be supported by two other fields of inquiry, what the Stoics called “logic” and “physics.” Together, these form the three topoi of Stoicism.

The logic and physics allow reason to aid us in living virtuously. However, these early views [underdetermined the Stoic virtue ethics](https://www.iep.utm.edu/stoicism/#H3):

> On balance, it seems fair to say that the ancient Stoics did believe in a (physical) god that they equated with the rational principle organizing the cosmos, and which was distributed throughout the universe in a way that can be construed as pantheistic. While it is the case that they maintained that an understanding of the cosmos informs the understanding of ethics, construed as the study of how to live one’s life, it can also be reasonably argued that Stoic metaphysics underdetermined—on the Stoics’ own conception—their ethics, thus leaving room for a “God or Atoms” position that may have developed as a concession to the criticisms of the Epicureans, who were atomists.

According to Pugliucci [contemporary Stoicism](https://www.iep.utm.edu/stoicism/#H6) as presented by Lawrence Becker is modified in three ways which may make it more compatible with modern materialism:

> There are three important differences between his New Stoicism and the ancient variety: (i) Becker defends an interpretation of the inherent primacy of virtue in terms of maximization of one’s agency, and builds an argument to show that this is, indeed, the preferred goal of agents that are relevantly constituted like a normal human being; (ii) he interprets the Stoic dictum, “follow nature” as “follow the facts” (that is, abide by whatever picture of the universe our best science allows). Stoic sources consistently attested to their respect for what we would today call scientific inquiry, as well as with an updated Stoic approach to epistemology; and (iii) Becker does away with the ancient Stoic teleonomic view of the cosmos, precisely because it is no longer supported by our best scientific understanding.

When one claims one is a Stoic today, one way to test whether that is accurate is to what extent one agrees or not with Lawrence Becker's presentation of it in *A New Stoicism*.

---

Massimo Pigliucci. Stoicism. Retrieved on June 12, 2019 from *Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy* at https://www.iep.utm.edu/stoicism/

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Frank, I will check out and read A New Stoicism to update my knowledge and decide whether I really agree with  the modern stoic philosophy as all my resources are from ancient philosophy  Best

Comment: @SmootQ Becker's book may indeed be the only _academic_ modern attempt to update Stoicism. However as far as I know it is a difficult book and is little read and little mentioned, among modern Stoics. I would recommend Massimo Pigliucci's numerous blog posts on Stoicism, and also the facebook groups that discuss Stoicism.

Comment: @RamTobolski Thank you for the reference, I will check both resources, Massimo Pigliucci is well known and prominent stoic. Best !

Comment: @SmootQ You're welcome. Here is another recommended book, recent and authoritative https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B07DPPCYK9/ref=tmm_kin_title_0?ie=UTF8&qid=&sr=

Comment: @RamTobolski Thanks again, I'll check it out. Best ^^ !

Comment: As you say,  it can reasonably be argued that Stoic metaphysics is underdetermined. That is to say, it is a muddle and is not capable of justifying its ethics. I do not believe Pigliucci is a safe guide to Stoicism, but at least the way in which he ignores metaphysics seems typical. .